# Entity Framework conditional mapping with code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have an entity that I need to return only records where a given field value is greater than zero. I have seen examples of conditional mapping in the edmx and that seems like what I am in need of. However, my project is in EF 4.1 code first. 
Is there not a way to do this using the code first approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think there is an inbuilt method for achieving this, you can however expose a property in your DbContext in which you apply filtering, initially this will be readonly but i dont see a reason why you shouldnt be able to create your own DbSet implementation reflecting back to another DbSet (ProxyDbSet)

Readonly example:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<User> Admins 
    {
        get 
        {
            return from user in users
                   where user.Role == "admin"
                   select user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Polity. If i understand correctly, this would result in EF returning my entire recordset and then assigning the linq-filtered set to the, in your example, Admins IQuaryable property. I was hoping not to do this as the entire set will be quite large. However, from what I can tell, this may be the best solution. Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: @RockyMountainHigh - No it wont actually, Note that DbSet implements IQueryable as well as the method itself returning IQueryable. This means that Calling admin wont return anything but a definition of a query. As soon as you start doing a foreach over the result of Admins, a SQL query will be generated including a where filter on the role of users. Therefore, this is just as efficient as conditional mapping

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Learn something new today? Check!