# Entity Framework, soft-deleting and queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

So here's my situation:

I'm soft-deleting some rows in a table, using a `IsDeleted` flag, so that a can keep a trace of my archived data. I do so by overriding the `SaveChanges` statement in my `ObjectContext`.

The question is: how can I select only the row(s) that have `IsDeleted == false`, without having to specify `&& !IsDeleted` in every queries?

Is there a way I can specify this on my context directly?

tkx!

Comment: EF Code-first or Model-first?

Comment: Instead of Flag, use a table.  For the deleted table the PK can be the same PK as the main table, with the deleted table's PK a FK to the main table.  If you got a record in deleted, then its deleted, if not active.  Then its just a simple join.  Query performance will be better than using a bit flag.

Comment: @JonRaynor: Databases aren't my specialty, but it seems to me that checking a bit flag has got to be a lot less expensive than doing a join, especially since you're usually going to be more interested in knowing which items *aren't* deleted (and therefore aren't present in the deleted table). If the bit flag is hurting query performance, I'd prefer an index over creating a completely separate table.

Comment: @Stripling - On the surface, that looks to be correct.  I've asked a followup, here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856684/soft-delete-use-isdeleted-flag-or-separate-joiner-table

Answer (score 8):

You could define a view over your table and query that view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ActiveData
AS
  SELECT (list of columns)
  FROM dbo.YourTable
  WHERE IsDeleted = 0
```

And then in your EDMX model, read your data from the `ActiveData` view instead of the base table.

Answer (score 7):

If you right-click an EntitySet in the model viewer, and click "Table Mapping", there is an area where you can "Add a Condition". This should do what you're asking, although you might be better off using a View instead, as per marc_s's suggestion.

Comment: Conditional mapping is correct way to go in EF. Using view as @marc suggested works but it will require additional changes.

Comment: How would you do conditional mapping with code-first, without a physical edmx?

Comment: @olivehour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161689/entity-framework-conditional-mapping-with-code-first

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks, that's basically what we do, although via IQueryable / IEnumerable extension methods rather than directly on the context.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: When you add the condition IsDeleted = false to the entity, the entity can no longer contain IsDeleted in the edmx file. So how do you delete entities if IsDeleted can't be part of the entity?

Comment: @Bumper: I'd personally put a trigger on the table to capture deletion, and then let Entity Framework actually issue a "delete from ..." instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but for anyone new coming here. As of EF 6 you really should be using interceptors for this type of query. It places a query inside of the SQL query as it runs and filters records based on the flag.

See the following for more info:

[Soft Deleting Entities using Interceptors](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html)